# Sprouting 4 Oclocks

Tags: flowers, planting-times

I have let 4 Oclocks run loose in part of my yard for several years; sprouts and new plants all over. I wanted to plant some in a open woods ( sandy loam ): I gathered fresh seeds and planted hundreds 2 months ago. A range of depths from 0 to 1+ inches. We have had good rain. I don't see sprouts. Do these seeds need to age or dry out first? The sprouts in my yard may be from few year old seeds.

Answer (score 3):

If they haven't germinated yet, they may not germinate at all, or more likely, some might do so next spring/early summer. It's usual to sow these indoors a few weeks before the last frost date,then transfer outside later as plants, or to sow seed in spring after the last frost date. Self sown plants usually germinate the following spring. Info here http://homeguides.sfgate.com/start-mirabilis-jalapa-seeds-65094.html